# How do I query the value at the start of each week?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to run a query that returns the stock level at the start of each calendar week. More specifically I want to find the last event before the start of each calendar week.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sku, warehouse
                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rnk
  FROM inventory_value
  WHERE timestamp < CAST('2018-11-01' as DATE)
) WHERE rnk = 1
```

The query should be something like this, except that I want it to be for every week after a start date.

Example input data looks like this

```
    sku         warehouse   timestamp               SOH
1   12345678    W31         2018-09-25 14:00:00.000 2322
2   12345678    W31         2018-11-16 00:00:00.000 0
```

And at the start of each week I want to return the row immediately preceding it.

For instance for every week in before 16th of November I want it to return the event in September, but all weeks after 16 November I want to get the event from the 16th.

I am happy to give the query a start date, but for my application I can't modify the query on a weekly basis.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can oyu please give sample data  your query seems fine

Comment: I will try to prepare some data. The query works fine, except that I don't want to hardcode the date. I want it to return it on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

From your original query you would opt for partitioning by the records by  date_trunc(week,timestamp), followed by ordering of timestamp field

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
      SELECT *
             ,rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sku
                                       ,warehouse
                                       ,date_trunc('week',timestamp)
                               ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rnk
        FROM inventory_value      
      )x
WHERE x.rnk = 1
```

Comment: Sorry bit of a beginner here, but where can I get the week value from, as it stands it is not part of the inventory_value table

Comment: I guess week should be in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

see  if it  works:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sku,warehouse, to_char(trunc(timestamp) - 7/24,'IW'),
                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rnk
  FROM inventory_value
  WHERE timestamp < (select MAX(timestamp ) from inventory_value)
) WHERE rnk = 1
```